# What's the input dimension for transformer decoder during TRAINING?

Tags: machine-learning

For example, translate English sentence A to French sentence B.
During training with ith word in B, all previous words before B will be fed to decoder, whose length will change for different i. How this is handled so that it can fit into a fixed dimension in the final linear layer during TRAINING?

Answer (score 0):

For feeding word one by one in transformer network we pass the whole sentence along with a mask to the network. And the mask will do the job by unmasking one new word at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much.